# Java to Java conversation through REST: Share a jar with class definitions?

Tags: java, json, rest

Say a Java program A calls another Java program B through REST. A needs to transfer some complex data (not really suitable for simple key-value pairs) to B.

I thought about doing it in the following way:

1. Define a `shared-datatypes.jar` which contains a `Parameter` class.
2. Add this jar as a dependency in both A and B.
3. In A, convert an object of type `Parameter` to JSON, send it over the wire, and convert it back in B.

This can be easily done through e.g. GSON and avoids errors of manually building JSON, but it requires an additional jar that is loaded on both sides.

Is this advisable? Or am I reinventing something that already exists in a better way?

Comment: As far as I know, this is considered to be an anti-pattern in microservices.

Comment: @lexicore What is the pattern you would use instead?

Comment: Develop client and server independently.

Comment: @lexicore How do I handle complex parameters?

Comment: Which specific difficulties do you have with handling complex parameters?

Comment: I have a Java Object, that consists of subobjects, which contain Maps etc. I need the same kind of object on both sides. What I can do is take this object apart and transport it as a number of Maps, Lists etc. . On the other side, I build a similar object from this Maps, Lists etc. It just seems like wasted effort and code duplication.

Comment: Yes, you'd implement the same class on both sides. That's the price for independence. Developing such classes is normally quite trivial so in reality it is not a problem. But it is quite nice, for instance, to read only the needed attributes and ignoring everything else. Or being able to add a few methods on clients (which the server does not need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good approach if you want strict control over how the JSON is to be deserialized to a concrete Java object e.g. `Parameter`

Alternatively, Java project A and project B would have their "local" versions of `Parameter` with only the fields from the JSON that the project actually needs.

This alternative approach would work well if for example there is a project C which needs a new field, and now project A needs to add a new field (let's call it `transactionNumber`) but project B does not care for `transactionNumber` since it does not need it. Now with your proposed approach, all 3 projects would most likely need the new version of `shared-datatypes.jar` and newly joining developers on project B could become confused on whether or not this `transactionNumber` is necessary or not. (It increases the *noise-to-signal* ratio on what's important in the codebase.)

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of the old DCOM days and defining binary objects to be sent/consumed on the wire.

I've done this before in Java as a way to allow many separate parts of a distributed system to understand messages sent among them. I created a completely separate project, just for the communications objects which produced messages-1.0.0.jar for example.

Each system's maven project then included this artifact as a dependency so they all had the same version of the messages project. You can define the dependency in the parent pom so it only needs to be updated in one place on each new release of the messages project.

The messages project was an XMLBeans configuration against the distributed XMLSchema that defined the enterprise message formats. Building this project compiled XMLSchema files to Java object hierarchies so none of the other parts of the enterprise system needed to look at XML, ever. They just used the constructs from messages-1.0.0.jar

So your idea of using a shared jar is fine. Where XMLBeans gives you an object hierarchy for XML, GSON will give you the same abstraction for JSON, backed by your shared object definitions. The trick is keeping everything at the same version so some of your clients don't try to use an older version of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse the input like this:

> Map map = gson.fromJson(input, Map.class);

GSON will make a best effort to reflect the data as a Map of whatever it takes (Lists, other Maps, primitive types wrappers) that perfectly reflects the structure of the JSON you sent.

Pros: you would not need with this approach a new jar to be deployed to each end

Cons: what I propose is a weak solution that makes you lose any control on the schema of the data, since almost everything can be parsed that way without firing an exception.  In order to keep some kind of  control, it would force you to implement validations in the back end.  And you would of course lose any additional logic implemented in your shared-datatypes.jar

Answer (score 0):

May be there is another way, if so I am not aware of. We use your described scenario. We do have one REST service and several clients. E.g an angular client a java client. All of the clients will be created with the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) maven plugin.

Each client just uses the created client-api, and so no manual work todo.

More [about](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) swagger.